# image src from a var?

Tags: javascript, image

I have a var that contains a number and I want to store that in image src like:

```
var number = 10;
<img src="images\'+number+'.jpg">
```

i already have a picture with called 10.jpg

also how can I change a string to a number. for example if I use reg-exp to get a number from text how can I change it to a number ?

Answer (score 2):

To set the image source you can do

```
var image = document.getElementById("myImage"); 
image.src = number + ".jpg";
```

You can change a string into a number using the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

```
parseInt("10");
```

or

```
parseInt("10", 10);
```

where the second parameter is the radix representing the number system.

Comment: why this is not working var number = 10;
<img src="images\'+number+'.jpg">

Comment: @MaanSahir it's not working, because you have to escape the "\", with a "\\".

Comment: @MaanSahir Actually, is there a reason why you're using "\" instead of "/"?

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuery

```
var number = $("#imageid").attr('src').replace(".jpg", "");
```

Comment: I believe the OP already has `10` and is just looking to change to number. Also, this is a jquery example and the OP didn't specify jquery. JavaScript was tagged in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of time, here's the jQuery solution

```
var myVar = "10";
$("#myImage").attr("src",myVar+".jpg");
```

to convert a string to base 10 integer, @Garett's answer is usable

```
var myVarAsInt = parseInt("10", 10);
```

Comment: The OP said that a reg-ex is used to get the number and did not specify jquery.

Comment: @jk. The OP had two questions: 1) how to set `img.src` and 2) how to parse the number.

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh OK, but where is jquery specified in the question? jquery adds to the page load. If it's not needed or requested for a simple task, it shouldn't be used.